# scale, resize bmp structure, programming c

Tags: c, resize, structure, scale, bmp

my task is to scale bmp picture with the given factor:

***stream: base64 bmp image code:***

```
Qk1CAAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAABAAAAAEAAAABABgAAAAAAAwAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAA/////wAAAP8AAAAA
```

***scale.c***

```
struct bmp_image* scale(const struct bmp_image* image, float factor){
    if(image == NULL || factor <= 0){
        return NULL;
    }

    .........
    int width = bmp->header->width;
    int height = bmp->header->height;
    int widthNew = (int)round((float)width * factor);
    int heightNew = (int)round((float)height * factor);


    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < heightNew; y++){
        for(uint32_t z = 0; z< widthNew; z++){
            bmp->data[(y*widthNew)+z].red=image->data[(int)(floor((float)y/(float)factor)*width+floor((float)z/(float)factor))].red;
            bmp->data[(y*widthNew)+z].green=image->data[(int)(floor((float)y/(float)factor)*width+floor((float)z/(float)factor))].green;
            bmp->data[(y*widthNew)+z].blue=image->data[(int)(floor((float)y/(float)factor)*width+floor((float)z/(float)factor))].blue;
        }
    }

    return bmp;     
}
```

***main.c***

```
FILE *output_p8 = fopen("scale.bmp", "w");
    struct bmp_image* newimage8 = NULL;
    newimage8 = scale(image, 1.025656);  
    free_bmp_image(image);    
    write_bmp(output_p8,newimage8);
    free_bmp_image(newimage8);    
    fclose(output_p8);
```

the data output what I got after that:

```
ffffff ffffff ff0000 00ff00
```

the data what I should have:

```
ffffff ff0000 00ff00 000000
```

any suggest?

Comment: When you calculate the new width, you round to the next integer. Therefore, the effective scaling factor for your image is not the nominal factor. You must adjust your factor or (perhaps better) do all calculations by means of new and old width: `znew = zold * wnew / wold`. In your example, you scale a 1×4 pixel bitmap by a factor of 1.025656. Your new size is the basically same, so you don't scale the image, yet your new index for the second pixel is `floor(1 / 1.025656)`, which is 0 instead of 1.

Comment: You are indexing out of bounds in your for loop. The old width and height are smaller so by using y,z in your loop with the old width and height your indexing out of bounds. You also never increase the actual number of pixels

Comment: @MOehm can you explain for me what is ```znew = zold * wnew / wold```

Comment: They are the new and old z indices and widths, it can be read as `z_new = z_old * w_new / w_old`. I haven't used your nomenclature, because long words don't work that well in comments. You don't use a new index anyway, but a long, repeated expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you calculate the new dimensions, you perform a floating-point calculation and then round to the nearest integer:

```
int widthNew = round(width * factor);
```

(You don't need the casts: `factor` is a `float` and the result of a multiplication of an integer with a `float` is also a `float`; `widthNew` is an integer, so the `float` result must be converted to an integer.)

Because you round, your effective scaling factor (let's call it `factor_eff`) may differ from the nominal `factor`:

```
float factor_eff = (float) widthNew / width;
```

In your case:

```
factor == 1.025656;
width == 4;
widthNew == round(1.025656 * 4) == round(4.102624) == 4;
factor_eff = 4.0 / 4 == 1.0;
```

But you do your index calculations with the old factor:

```
int zNew = floor(z / factor);
```

(Again, you don't need the cast.) For your four z indces, this will yield:

```
z == 0;    zNew == floor(0 / 1.025656) == floor(0.0)       == 0;   // ok
z == 1;    zNew == floor(1 / 1.025656) ~~ floor(0.9749858) == 0;   // ! should be 1
z == 2;    zNew == floor(2 / 1.025656) ~~ floor(1.9499715) == 1;   // ! should be 2
z == 3;    zNew == floor(3 / 1.025656) ~~ floor(2.9249573) == 2;   // ! should be 3
```

You could fix the floating-point factor, but I think it is better (and faster) to calculate your new indices with integer arithmetic:

```
int zNew = z * width / widthNew;
int yNew = y * height / heightNew;
```

Make sure you do the multiplication first. This method should be safe to use for dimensions up to abour 46,000.